Constructing wave equation for known dispersion relation
Hello,
I am wondering how to construct differential wave equation for a given dispersion relation.
Simplest wave equation (constant wave velocity for all frequencies) is as follows:$$\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial t}^2}-c^2\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial x}^2}=0$$
Now let's assume that some medium is linear and its dispersion relation is known. Two purely hypothetical examples:
$c(f)=f+1$$c(f)=\sin(f)$
Now, an arbitrary wave can be thought as being composed of superposition of waves with some amplitude for a given frequency, I think that distribution should be integrated to yield full wave:$$u(t,x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(A(f)\sin(2\pi f(\frac x{c(f)}-t))+B(f)\cos(2\pi f(\frac x{c(f)}-t))) df$$
Now, I thought that wave equation should be modified to include frequency dependency:$$\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial t}^2}-c(f)^2\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial x}^2}=0$$
Inserting two realtions above, I will get these two equations for these examples:
$\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial t}^2}-(f^2+2f+1)\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial x}^2}=0$
$\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial t}^2}-\sin^2(f)\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial x}^2}=0$
Let's expand sine squared for later analysis:
$\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial t}^2}-(f^2+2f+1)\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial x}^2}=0$
$\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial t}^2}-(f^2-\frac{f^4}3+\frac{2 f^6}{45}-\frac{f^8}{315}+ \frac{2 f^{10}}{14175}-...)\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial x}^2}=0$
I think that there is a problem now with time/frequency pair as these two seem to be related to each other. To obtain final equation, I think that I can substitute time representation of "multiply by f" operator:$$f^n={(\frac1{2\pi i})}^n\frac{\partial^n}{{\partial t}^n}$$
$\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial t}^2}-({(\frac1{2\pi i})}^2\frac{\partial^2}{{\partial t}^2}+2(\frac1{2\pi i})\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+1)\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial x}^2}=0$
$\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial t}^2}-({(\frac1{2\pi i})}^2\frac{\partial^2}{{\partial t}^2}-\frac13{(\frac1{2\pi i})}^4\frac{\partial^4}{{\partial t}^4}+\frac{2}{45}{(\frac1{2\pi i})}^6\frac{\partial^6}{{\partial t}^6}-\frac{1}{315}{(\frac1{2\pi i})}^8\frac{\partial^8}{{\partial t}^8}+\frac{2}{14175}{(\frac1{2\pi i})}^{10}\frac{\partial^{10}}{{\partial t}^{10}}-...)\frac{\partial^2u}{{\partial x}^2}=0$
Now the question that I have, is my resoning correct and I obtained correct equations? If not at which step I made a mistake?

The opposite procedure, finding the dispersion relation starting from the wave equation, is simpler. This is well covered in the massive textbook "Modern Classical Physics" by Thorne&Blandford (Optics Section, as far as I can remember). However, I'd argue it can be run in reverse. You simply have to start with the ansatz $\psi(x,t)=A\exp\left(i(kx-\omega t)\right)$ and propose a wave equation that matches $\omega(k)$ by inspection. For example
$$\omega(k) = ck^2 $$
knowing that
$$\partial_t \psi = -i\omega\psi \ ; \ \partial_x = ik\psi, $$
then the wave equation must be of the form
$$-i\partial_t\psi = c \ \partial^2_x\psi, $$
where the $i$ term is fundamental. You can check that this is the kind of dispersion relation obtained from the Schrödinger equation.
